# How to cURL PUT with complicated arguments?

Tags: rest, curl, artifactory, http-put

**Note**: Although this question involves the Artifactory API it really is more about writing semi-sophisticated cURL commands.

Say I am in a directory that has `myapp-1.5.jar` in it. Let's also say I have an Artifactory repo located at `http://artrepo01:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local`.

I want to deploy the JAR to:

```
libs-release-local/
    myorg/
        myapp/
            1.5/
                myapp-1.5.jar
```

According to the [Artifactory API docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API?showChildren=false) (for **Deploy Artifact** endpoint), the proper way to do this is via HTTP PUT:

```
PUT /libs-release-local/my/jar/1.0/jar-1.0.jar
{
    "uri": "http://artrepo01:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local",
    "downloadUri": "http://artrepo01:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local",
    "repo": "libs-release-local",
    "path": "/myorg/myapp/1.5/myapp-1.5.jar",
    "createdBy": "artadmin",
    "mimeType": "application/java-archive",
}
```

Questions:

- What would the exact cURL command be to properly HTTP PUT the JAR to this endpoint?
- When I try `curl -X PUT http://artrepo01:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/myorg/myapp/1.5/myapp.jar` (which may or may not be correct in which case don't worry about the question above), I get an error from Artifactory stating that the **anonymous** user doesn't have write permissions to the repo. I *believe* this is because my cURL command isn't specifying the `createdBy` user (`artadmin`).
- How do I specify the password for the `artadmin` user in the PUT call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is good. Just add username and password using `-u` flag:

`curl -X PUT -u artadmin:password http://artrepo01:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/myorg/myapp/1.5/myapp-1.5.jar`